# Multiple Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1 in journalctl

Tags: debian

I'm running Debian 8 and I'm trying to troubleshoot issues with a server (random unresponsiveness) and one of the things I'm looking at, but do not understand, are hundreds of these entries, per minute, when I run journalctl --no-full -f

```
Aug 05 20:36:12 server sshd[48741]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Aug 05 20:36:12 server sshd[48741]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Aug 05 20:36:12 server sshd[48883]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Aug 05 20:36:12 server sshd[48883]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Aug 05 20:36:13 server sshd[48738]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Aug 05 20:36:13 server sshd[48738]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Aug 05 20:36:13 server sshd[47321]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
```

They are just constantly scrolling down the screen. Occasionally there will be a `Aug 05 20:40:04 server sshd[56623]: Accepted publickey for root from 127.0.0.1 port 45873 ssh2: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` and then it will go back to the above barrage of entries.

Would I be right to assume that this may be some kind of attack? or could it be something else? I have already changed the default port from 22 to another one.

Not quite sure what to make of it or if I should worry about it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like something you set up yourself, to ssh to localhost.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, it could be. I do have connections from other servers via SSH, but would this cause these constant messages? I had assumed(!) that they would stay connected permanently. If that is the case, this is not the cause of my issue as I've had this in place for ages. Thank you.

Comment: I use this in the crontab (from other servers) but this is only at startup, would this cause these logs? `sshfs -o password_stdin,nonempty,allow_other,reconnect`

Comment: These connections are on the local host.